# Corrupt AVFrame returned by libavcodec

Tags: c++, multithreading, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

As part of a bigger project, I'm trying to decode a number of HD (1920x1080) video streams simultaneously. Each video stream is stored in raw yuv420p format within an AVI container. I have a **Decoder** class from which I create a number of objects within different threads (one object per thread). The two main methods in Decoder are `decode()` and `getNextFrame()`, which I provide the implementation for below.

When I separate the decoding logic and use it to decode a single stream, everything works fine. However, when I use the multi-threaded code, I get a segmentation fault and the program crashes within the processing code in the decoding loop. After some investigation, I realized that the data array of the `AVFrame` filled in `getNextFrame()` contains addresses which are out of range (according to gdb).

I'm really lost here! I'm not doing anything that would change the contents of the `AVFrame` in my code. The only place where I attempt to access the AVFrame is when I call `sws_scale()` to convert the color format and that's where the segmentation fault occurs in the second case because of the corrupt `AVFrame`. Any suggestion as to why this is happening is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The `decode()` method:

```
void decode() {

    QString filename("video.avi");

    AVFormatContext* container = 0;

    if (avformat_open_input(&container, filename.toStdString().c_str(), NULL, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename.toStdString().c_str());
        exit(1);
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(container, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find file info..\n");
    }

    // find a video stream
    int stream_id = -1;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < container->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (container->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            stream_id = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (stream_id == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find a video stream..\n");
    }

    av_dump_format(container, stream_id, filename.toStdString().c_str(), false);

    // find the appropriate codec and open it
    AVCodecContext* codec_context = container->streams[stream_id]->codec;   // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream

    AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_decoder(codec_context->codec_id);  // Find the decoder for the video stream

    if (codec == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find a suitable codec..\n");
        return -1; // Codec not found
    }


    // Inform the codec that we can handle truncated bitstreams -- i.e.,
    // bitstreams where frame boundaries can fall in the middle of packets
    if (codec->capabilities & CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED)
        codec_context->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_TRUNCATED; 

    fprintf(stderr, "Codec: %s\n", codec->name);

    // open the codec
    int ret = avcodec_open2(codec_context, codec, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open the needed codec.. Error: %d\n", ret);
        return -1;
    }


    // allocate video frame 
    AVFrame *frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();  // deprecated, should use av_frame_alloc() instead

    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame..\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int frameNumber = 0;

    // as long as there are remaining frames in the stream
    while  (getNextFrame(container, codec_context, stream_id, frame)) {

        // Processing logic here...
        // AVFrame data array contains three addresses which are out of range

    }

    // freeing resources
    av_free(frame);

    avcodec_close(codec_context);

    avformat_close_input(&container);
}
```

The `getNextFrame()` method:

```
bool getNextFrame(AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx,
                  AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx,
                  int videoStream,
                  AVFrame *pFrame) {

    uint8_t inbuf[INBUF_SIZE + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];

    char buf[1024];

    int len;

    int got_picture;
    AVPacket avpkt;

    av_init_packet(&avpkt);

    memset(inbuf + INBUF_SIZE, 0, FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);

    // read data from bit stream and store it in the AVPacket object
    while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &avpkt) >= 0) {

        // check the stream index of the read packet to make sure it is a video stream
        if(avpkt.stream_index == videoStream) {

            // decode the packet and store the decoded content in the AVFrame object and set the flag if we have a complete decoded picture
            avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &got_picture, &avpkt);

            // if we have completed decoding an entire picture (frame), return true
            if(got_picture) {

                av_free_packet(&avpkt);

                return true;
            }
        }

        // free the AVPacket object that was allocated by av_read_frame
        av_free_packet(&avpkt);
    }

    return false;

}
```

The lock management callback function:

```
static int lock_call_back(void ** mutex, enum AVLockOp op) {
    switch (op) {
        case AV_LOCK_CREATE:
            *mutex = (pthread_mutex_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
            pthread_mutex_init((pthread_mutex_t *)(*mutex), NULL);
            break;
        case AV_LOCK_OBTAIN:
            pthread_mutex_lock((pthread_mutex_t *)(*mutex));
            break;
        case AV_LOCK_RELEASE:
            pthread_mutex_unlock((pthread_mutex_t *)(*mutex));
            break;
        case AV_LOCK_DESTROY:
            pthread_mutex_destroy((pthread_mutex_t *)(*mutex));
            free(*mutex);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the corruption occur on the same decoded frame of the same input every time? If so then you should upload the input to a file sharing site so people can attempt to reproduce. Also, it may come down to a bug (maybe already fixed) in `libavcodec/device`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the cause of the problem. It is the `av_free_packet()` call before returning when a decoded frame is obtained. I commented out that call and the program worked! I'm still not quite sure why this affects the filled `AVFrame` though.

I'm also not sure if removing that call would cause a memory leak in my code.

Hopefully a **libavcodec** expert can shed some light on this and explain what I was doing wrong.

Comment: I've just run into this problem today. As for why it deallocates the frame when you free the packet, is because the frame just holds a reference to all its packets so no data is duplicated but I could be wrong.